# Sed replace all matches after some patterns

Tags: linux, sed

I want to replace all B after '='.

```
echo A, B = A B B A B B B | sed 's/=\(.*\)B\(.*\)/=\1C\2/g'
```

The expected result should be

```
A, B = A C C A C C C
```

But I got this result:

```
A, B = A B B A B B C
```

Only the last matched pattern be replaced. How to resolve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this `sed`:

```
sed ':loop; s/\(=.*\)B\(.*\)/\1C\2/; t loop'
```

**Test:**

```
$ echo A, B = A B B A B B B | sed ':loop; s/\(=.*\)B\(.*\)/\1C\2/; t loop'
A, B = A C C A C C C
```

Comment: Work on Linux, but OSX still fail, any ideas?

Comment: use `-e` instead of some `;`. Command is thus  `sed -e ':loop' -e 's/\(=.*\)B\(.*\)/\1C\2/; t loop'`

Comment: Try this: `sed -e ':loop' -e 's/\(=.*\)B\(.*\)/\1C\2/' -e 't loop'`

Comment: The second back reference is perhaps superfluous. Also consider what would happen if you want to change `B` to `BC`?

Answer (score 0):

Same kind of idea as @sat but starting from beginning of string

```
sed -e ':cycle' -e 's/\(.*=.*\)B/\1C/;t cycle'
```

posix compliant so should works on any sed